# Google Play Store Android 10

Tags: chromium, chromium-embedded

Google Play Store had stopped accepting app with targetSdkVersion 28.

Answer (score 2):

See it
https://github.com/ardabeyazoglu/cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview-v3/issues/9

> android 10+ crosswalk is indeed not working, and there is no way to make it work because original crosswalk project is archived. I recommend you drop crosswalk for android 7+ devices

This is a developer’s comment.
I think you don’t have any way to work properly.

Comment: Hi. 
actually, my project decided to detach crosswalk for this reason. 
So, All I can is a recommendation for you not to put off repayment of technical dept.